# How can I write this text aligned?

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment

I'm trying to do a Beamer presentation and I have to write the following text. I would like to get the same aligned as in the picture, but I'm not sure how to do that. I have tried creating two columns but it fails.

What I want is that the equations start at the same point, in spite of the ending position of the text in the left-hand side.

[image: What I need]

Comment: See [How to align similar math expressions listed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41732208/914686)

Comment: Put everything in a table. With three columns you could use the mid one for the math symbols left of the equal and thus get a nice alignment of the equations.

Comment: Can you give a MWE to save us from re-typing everything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others already have mentioned, this can easily be achieved by using a tabular like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
\textbf{Predict}  &  \\
Predicted state estimate            & $\displaystyle\hat{\mathbf{x}}_{k-1|k-1}=f(\hat{\mathbf{x}}_{k|k-1},\mathbf{k}_{u-1})$ \\
Predicted covariance estimate       & $\displaystyle\hat{\mathbf{x}}_{k-1|k-1}=f(\hat{\mathbf{x}}_{k|k-1},\mathbf{k}_{u-1})$ \\[.5em]
\textbf{Update}   &  \\
Innovation or measurement residual  & $\displaystyle\hat{\mathbf{x}}_{k-1|k-1}=f(\hat{\mathbf{x}}_{k|k-1},\mathbf{k}_{u-1})$ \\
Innovation (or residual) covariance & $\displaystyle\hat{\mathbf{x}}_{k-1|k-1}=f(\hat{\mathbf{x}}_{k|k-1},\mathbf{k}_{u-1})$ \\
Near-optimal Kalman gain            & $\displaystyle\hat{\mathbf{x}}_{k-1|k-1}=f(\hat{\mathbf{x}}_{k|k-1},\mathbf{k}_{u-1})$ \\
Updated state estimate              & $\displaystyle\hat{\mathbf{x}}_{k-1|k-1}=f(\hat{\mathbf{x}}_{k|k-1},\mathbf{k}_{u-1})$ \\
Updated covariance estimate         & $\displaystyle\hat{\mathbf{x}}_{k-1|k-1}=f(\hat{\mathbf{x}}_{k|k-1},\mathbf{k}_{u-1})$ 
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: What's the purpose of the `\displaystyle` directives?

Answer (score 2):

Use a simple tabular:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\subsection*{Update}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{} p{7cm} >{$}l<{$} @{}}
Innovation or measurement residual & 
     \overline{\mathbf{y}}_k = \mathbf{Z}_k - h(\mathbf{\hat{x}}_{k|k-1}) \\[5pt]
Innovation (or residual) covariance &
     \mathbf{S}_k = \mathbf{H}_k \ldots
 \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]